# Any reason why the choice_attr in Symfony3 ChoiceType can't set the id attribute?

Tags: symfony

I have created a Symfony3 form class with the following ChoiceType element for my form:

```
->add('deg_certs', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'mapped' => false,
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'label' => 'Degrees/Certificates received:',
        'choices' => array(
                'BA/BS' => 'ba_bs',
                'AA/AS' => 'aa_as',
                'Voc. Cert.' => 'voc_cert',
                'Other' => 'other',
        ),
        'choice_attr' => function($val){
            return ['class' => $val];
        },
))
```

This works fine and sets the class attribute to the choice value. But I want to instead set the id attribute.

I've tried this:

```
'choice_attr' => function($val){
    return ['id' => $val];
},
```

Which I was expecting to work but doesn't.

I also tried in my Twig template this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.deg_certs[3],
    {'attr':{'id':'deg_other',
    'onchange':'changeDegCertOther()',
    'style':'float:left'}}) }}
```

But that doesn't set the id attribute either. Note: the above is trying to set the id of the 3rd item in the choices in case you are not familar.

This appears to be an issue with the Symfony3 code not supporting this. Can anyone confirm?

The reason I want to set the id attribute, is because in my Javascript I want to use `getElementById` not `getElementsByClassName` (which gets an array).

Comment: Probably because `id` is set by the Form class based on the field name. You could set a `data-` attribute like so: `return ['data-id' => $val]`, and then [`var el = document.querySelector('[data-id="+the_id_you_set+"]')`](https://jsfiddle.net/rjyjfb84/).

Comment: Thanks for that info @JaredFarrish . Yes setting 1he `data-id` does work like you've indicated. My concern is that it appears to be an issue with the [choice_attr code](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr). According to that documentation, you should be able to set an attribute for any element of the choice array. I wonder if there's a place to submit a Symfony bug. I have workarounds, but I still think it's a bug. Plus I've seen other issues.

Comment: If only Symfony used github for source and issue control. Oh wait, it does. Anyways, id works as designed.  Have the form component generate the id is the only way to guarantee a unique id for nested forms.

Comment: Hi @Cerad. Thanks for the feedback. You tend to be sarcastic. Yes, it's working based on the fact it makes the ids equal to `formname_element#`; but since using a function with `class` and `data-id` seems to work, it's odd that `id` doesn't work. I might look at submitting a bug, and maybe even fixing it. Again thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I've explained in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20965 why this is expected and how to work around that.