# Can we define the id attribute of a widget in a form from a Symfony controller?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'd like to define the [id attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_id.asp) of a widget in a form using a [form class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes).

From a Twig view, [the Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-widget-view-variables) show us how to add a "foo" class attribute:

```
{{ form_widget(form.surname, {'attr': {'class': 'foo'}}) }}
```

This can be done from the form class using:

```php
$builder->add('surname', TextType::class, [
    'attr' => ['class' => 'foo'],
])
```

So, if we can change the class attribute like this, we could suppose we can change the id attribute like the following:

```
{{ form_widget(form.title, { 'attr': {'id': 'my_custom_id'} }) }}
```

However this does not work, we need to define the id outside of the `attr` array like the following:

```
{{ form_widget(form.surname, { 'id': 'my_custom_id' }) }}
```

Based on that observation, if I try to define the id outside of the `attr` from the form class like this:

```php
$builder->add('surname', TextType::class, [
    'id' => 'my_custom_id',
])
```

But this is not allowed, I get the following:

> The option "id" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "method", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "required", "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message", "validation_groups".

I noticed we can't define the id inside of the `attr` array for a [widget](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-widget-view-variables) while we can do it inside of the `label_attr` array for a [label](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-label-view-label-variables), even from the form class.

Is it possible to define the id of a widget from a form class? If so, how to do it?

**EDIT:** I'd like to mention that I tested the following and only the id of the label changed.

```php
->add('surname', TextType::class, [
    'label_attr' => ['id' => 'my_custom_id1'],
    'attr' => ['id' => 'my_custom_id2'],
])
```

I'm using Symfony v3.3.6

**EDIT2:** I created [a sandbox project that reproduces the issue](https://github.com/Kwadz/sf-widget-custom-id).

Comment: Downvoter: at least explain why you downvoted as it's a common courtesy here...

Comment: I think a bigger question is why?  What issue are you having with the id that Symfony auto-generates?

Comment: I wanted to customize the id attributes and I noticed this issue which I wanted to point out. If there is no way, yes I'll use the ones auto-generated by Symfony.

Comment: You can do it in Twig like you've discovered, or you can use a modified Form Theme and override the values you need.  You can also modify the `getBlockPrefix()` in your form as well, even returning `''` if you want, which might help.

Comment: Hi, looks like I was wrong. The id was not being set the way I thought it was. You need to use Twig, like so: `{{ form_widget(form.surname, { 'id': 'my_custom_id' }) }}` Do you want me to delete my answer?

Comment: @Kwadz: the guidelines on voting are that "anyone may vote up or down for any reason, anonymously if they wish, as long as they do not focus on one particular user". A feature request to make giving a reason mandatory has been frequently rejected on _Meta Stack Overflow_. My own view is that this situation is not going to change, and requests in posts/comments for people to explain their vote make no difference - by the time you've commented, the voter has gone.

Comment: @halfer, yes most of the time the voter won't come back. I wanted to encourage to fully understand the issue, as I suspected a misunderstanding. That's why I also edited the question to add more details. In the end, I could have deleted the comment. On _Meta Stack Overflow_ there is also a [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive) about if asking reasons is constructive or not, opinions are divided...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, it's **not possible** as Symfony [generates ids for form types it renders](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20965#issuecomment-267674782).

In addition this is [unlikely to change in the core as that would also be a huge BC break to not generate it anymore](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20965#issuecomment-267761742).

We can only change the prefix of the id by overriding the `$view->vars['id']` like the following:

```
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{

    $view->vars['id'] = 'myprefix';
}
```

The suffix is the name defined in `$builder->add('surname', TextType::class)`. In this case the new id would be `myprefix_surname`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use `data-id` instead:

```
$builder
    ->add('surname', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Label:',
            'label_attr' => array(
                    'id' => 'custom_id1',
            ),
            'attr' => array(
                    'data-id' => 'custom_id2',
                    'class' => 'custom_id2',
            ),
    ))
;
```

I had a [similar problem with the ChoiceType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174777/any-reason-why-the-choice-attr-in-symfony3-choicetype-cant-set-the-id-attribute), so I'm wondering if `data-id` will work for you?