# How can I customize form fields IDs in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4, symfony-forms

I'm building a web page in Symfony that is built with multiple instances of the same form, but with different POST urls. I want to intercept the submit with javascript, and do a simple AJAX POST.

The structure of this page is this:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
{% for document in documents %}
    <div id="form_{{ document.id }}">
        {{ form(document.form) }}
        <input type="submit">Submit button</input>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<hr />
```

If I have 4 documents in the `documents` array, 4 forms will be rendered. The problem is that **all** the documents fields will have the same ID: there will be 4 `document_csrf`, 4 `document_title` title, and so, because all `documents` are views of the `DocumentType` form.

What I want is to add **something** to the generation of the form, so each form field is rendered with unique fieldnames: `document_csrf1`, `document_title_1`, `document_csrf2`, `document_title_2`, etc.

I've been looking around StackOverflow and the Symfony Documentation, but I can't find anything. I can pass an `['attr'] => ['id' => $id]]` then calling the `createForm` function, but this ID is only used for the `<form>` tag, not the other fields...

Is there any way to automatically add an ID to the form, or should I render the form adding the id to each element (`{{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'id': 'document_name' ~ document.id}}) }}`)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Set yourself up a form using a CollectionType for your documents and take a look at how twig deals with the ids. Might suggest an approach.

Comment: @Cerad I'm not sure this is a good idea: each document should be able to be sent independently from the others; this is the reason because I have a form for every document.

Comment: Fair enough.  The only way I can see is to mess with each individual id as shown in your question.  You might be able to write your own custom form templates but I suspect that would be a pain.

Comment: @Cerad thank you. No, I won't write a custom form template, because each form only has 2 fields and the CSRF...

Comment: I guess you can't do it: already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46124065/4820276)

Comment: you must probably change the intention parameter in the configureOptions method of your FormType via the $ resolver-> setDefaults (array ('intention' => 'document'))